# How to send image from server to android app in real time

Tags: android

I have an android application which is sending image to server (php).
I want to send image to application when new image will be uploaded to server. to have a php server ----> application connection and handler in application

How can I implement this to call application function from server ? (upload image to server I already have)

P.S. Google Cloud Message is exact what i need for my application but I can not use gcm . please advice me something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP server can send Push Notification to your application. Then you need to implement in your application how to handle this notification, which in your case is image downloading.

Read about Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... but I don't want to use google cloud messaging ... can you advise me something similar ?

Comment: Another way is checking server for new images with some interval (for example every 5 minutes) but then you will have some delay. If you don't want any delay, Push Notifications is the only solution. PS. Parse.com and Amazon Web Service has also Push services but I'm afraid that they use GCM under the hood.